# Protobuf version mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm currently getting this error using RNN in tensorflow:

> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program
>   requires version 3.3.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the
>   installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you
>   compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from
>   the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. 
>   (Version verification failed in
>   "bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/proto/fertile_stats.pb.cc".)
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>
> what():  This program requires version 3.3.0 of the Protocol Buffer
>   runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update
>   your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that
>   your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your
>   link-time library.  (Version verification failed in
>   "bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/proto/fertile_stats.pb.cc".)

But when I check the version:

```
$ pip show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.4.0
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: six, setuptools
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have two different versions of protobuf installed.
Check

`protoc --version`

If it is different from 3.4.0. You might need to uninstall it.

Comment: `protoc` doesn't exist in my case

Comment: What is the difference between "protoc --version" and "pip show protobuf"?

Comment: @Hari depends on the way you installed protobuf and who manages your installation.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

```
wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.17.3/protobuf-all-3.17.3.tar.gz -O /tmp/protobuf-all-3.17.3.tar.gz && \
tar xzvf /tmp/protobuf-all-3.17.3.tar.gz && \
cd protobuf-3.17.3 && \
mkdir build && \
cd build && \
cmake ../cmake && \
make && \
sudo make install && \
```

If you are getting the below cmake warning:

> CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):   Protobuf compiler version 3.0.0 doesn't match library version 3.17.3 Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

Then follow the below command:

```
sudo apt-get remove libprotobuf-dev
```

Suppress cmake warning

```
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are linking a c++ program using different libs. If these libs are built using with different version of protobuf, it will cause this problem. Rebuild all the libs (including tf) using the same version of protobuf.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking your protoc version using

```
protoc --version
```

making sure that you don't have another protoc in your system using

```
which protoc
```